# ways to enter data in another website and get revert from there

Tags: c#

I m looking for some code to enter data in another website without API,

Front end should be my website and in back end automatically the data enters in the another website and get revert from there and give me the message/proper content in my website..

So is there any type of code is available for that in c#??

Guys please suggest me if there is any way to do this.

I tried some web services but it didn't helped.

Comment: You might want to check 'Web Scrapping' techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion : You can have a single database for both of your web sites. from one site you can insert the data and you can use other website to retrieve it.